# Validate Laravel date format with Y-m-dTH:i:s

Tags: php, laravel, validation, datetime

I'm building an API and it should accept date and time value as the format of `Y-m-dTH:i:s`. The specialty of this is that there's `T`  in the middle between date and time.

So, how to write validation rule to check this?

```
'start_at' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s'
```

This is what I currently have.

Comment: Don't forget timezone.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try to use `\T` like this:

```
'start_at' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d\TH:i:s'
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm!

Comment: OMG, I was having this massive bug for days with my SaaS and I could not figure out the problem and this #*&%^ slash was the issue?? I feel better and thanks! but so frustrating lol.